# Mac OS Multiple Storyboards NSMenu first responder

Tags: swift, macos, storyboard, first-responder

I am trying to connect an NSMenuItem to the first responder of a class defined in storyboard other than the main storyboard where the menu is defined. Is there anyway to do that?

Comment: The first responder isn't a property of a class. See [First Responders](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/EventOverview/EventArchitecture/EventArchitecture.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/10000060i-CH3-SW24). Connect the menu item to the first responder proxy of the storyboard scene.

Comment: Maybe I didn't state it clearly, but I don't see anyway to connect it to the first responder other then for one in which the scene is in the main storyboard. So how do you connect a menu item to the a first responder in storyboard XXXX?

Comment: You can't. All first responder proxies are proxies of the same first responder. See [How can “First Responder” be used in a xib file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4652721/how-can-first-responder-be-used-in-a-xib-file)